# Keeping time-series while grouping by season in xarray

Tags: group-by, python-xarray

I would like to have the winter (DJF) average for every year to plot a time-series.

I know that I can group by season if I have a data array (DA). I don't know what to do next and all examples I seen are about seasonal average, which remove the temporal axis completely:

`DA.groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time').sel(season='DJF')`

I would like to do something like this:

`DA.groupby('time.season').sel(season='DJF').groupby('time.year').mean(dim='time')`

And have a data point for every winter of each year.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access the [datetime components](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#datetime-components) of your time dimension and use it for selecting & grouping.

What you want can be done with:

```py
# select DJF
DA_DJF = DA.sel(time=DA.time.dt.season=="DJF")

# calculate mean per year
DA_DJF.groupby(DA_DJF.time.dt.year).mean("time")
```

Comment: Note that this is incorrect for seasons as December is taken from the same year as January and Feb.  For DJF seasonal average, you have to take the Dec value from the previous year.  I am trying to figure out a way to include the year timestamp from a multi-year dataset (the groupby year above does not work for a correct DJF seasonal average because you have two years involved). @anne sophie

Answer (score 2):

There's an example on Xarray's [resample](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html) that shows how to downsample monthly time-series data to seasonal data. Asuming you have all months of the year, using

```
DA.resample(time='QS-DEC').mean(dim="time")
```

will give you the yearly timeseries of the averages of DJF, MAM, JJA, and SON. In this new series, DJF will have months=12, MAM will have months = 3, JJA will have months = 6, and SON will have months = 9.

It's important to note that the averages of DJF are asigned to the year of December and not the year of January-February.